# Чтение нескольких строк из консоли в C

Tags: c

Здравствуйте! Хочу считать из консоли две строки. Делаю это так:

```
char s[50];
int setA1[50], setA2[50];

// Читаю первую строку из чисел
fprintf(stdout, "Enter set A1:\n");
fscanf(stdin, "%[ 0123456789]", s);
fprintf(stdout, "A1: %s\n", s);

// Читаю вторую строку из чисел
fprintf(stdout, "Enter set A2:\n");
fscanf(stdin, "%[ 0123456789]", s);
fprintf(stdout, "A2: %s\n", s);

return 0;
```

Но вместо этого считывается только первый массив из чисел, а чтения второго не происходит, сразу выводится строка s, вот, что у меня в консоли происходит:

```
Enter set A1:
1 2 3
A1: 1 2 3
Enter set A2:
A2: 1 2 3
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём моя ошибка.

Comment: Предполагается, что строки имеют формат N1 N2 ... Nm, где Ni - целое число

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в буфере остается символ новой строки, а его читать вы не разрешаете. Вот он и мешает второму чтению. Сделайте так:

```
...
fprintf(stdout, "A1: %s\n", s);

while(fgetc(stdin) != '\n');

fprintf(stdout, "Enter set A2:\n");
...
```